# Mount a SMB share subfolder as a drive in iOS. IPhone

Tags: smb, iphone

On MacOS it's possible to map a subfolder of a shared volume.

Mounting:

```
$ mkdir /Volumes/togo
$ mount_smbfs smb://someserver/someshare/where/i/really/want/togo /Volumes/togo
```

As answered here : [Mount a SMB share's subfolder as a drive in OS X Lion](https://superuser.com/questions/390813/mount-a-smb-shares-subfolder-as-a-drive-in-os-x-lion)

Is it possible to do the same on a IPhone or IPad running the latest firmware? it always seem to mount the root of the share.

Comment: surely you can just go into the files app and connect to the server via smb://someserver/someshare/where/i/really/want/togo and itll appear in the files app (obviously you can't mount anything)

Comment: @Nathan Yesyou can actually mount it in the Files app. but it mounts the root and not the file. The problem is the path is too long to navigate to and the user only have acces to the end folder not all of the folder before.

Comment: A related point if anyone stumbles on this question whilst attempting to troubleshoot SMB access from iOS Files clients showing "unknown error".  As it insists on connecting to the root of the SMB server to enumerate the list of available shares - as pointed out by the OP - the Files client also seems to be using the `smb2` protocol to do so, resulting in inability to access anything if the server is configured globally to require `smb3`.  In my case, I had to move `server min protocol = SMB3` from the `[global]` section to the individual share configuration in Samba's `smb.conf` (server-side)